# unable to create an array of a specific object and unable to correctly use the compare to method

Tags: java, arrays, class, compareto

in this project, my goal is to sort an array of rational numbers (I have created a rational class which allows that). TO sort the array, I had to write a compareto method for the class (my class extends the comparable interface). But when i checked my compareto method, it always returns a 0 value. Also when I make an array of rational class elements, the program just keeps running at that point without outputting any results. I don't understand why? Below is my code, which also includes methods and parts :

```
public class MuhammadChaudryProject4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rational a = new Rational(1, 4);
        Rational b = new Rational(1, 8);

        System.out.println(a + " + " + b + " = " + a.add(b));
        System.out.println(a + " - " + b + " = " + a.sub(b));
        System.out.println(a + " * " + b + " = " + a.mul(b));
        System.out.println(a + " / " + b + " = " + a.div(b));

        Rational[] arr = {new Rational(7, 1), new Rational(6, 1),
                      new Rational(5, 1), new Rational(4, 1),
                      new Rational(3, 1), new Rational(2, 1),
                      new Rational(1, 1), new Rational(1, 2),
                      new Rational(1, 3), new Rational(1, 4),
                      new Rational(1, 5), new Rational(1, 6),
                      new Rational(1, 7), new Rational(1, 8),
                      new Rational(1, 9), new Rational(0, 1)};

       selectSort(arr);

       for (Rational r : arr) {
            System.out.println(r);
       }

       Number n = new Rational(7, 3);

       System.out.println(n.doubleValue());
       System.out.println(n.floatValue());
       System.out.println(n.intValue());
       System.out.println(n.longValue());
       }

 public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void selectSort(T[] array)        
 {

      T temp;
      int mini;

      for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; ++i) {

          mini = i;
          for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; ++j) {
               if (array[j].compareTo(array[mini]) < 0) {
                    mini = j;
                }
          }

         if (i != mini) {
             temp = array[i];
             array[i] = array[mini];
             array[mini] = temp;
             }
         }
         }
   }


   class Rational extends Number implements Comparable<Rational> {
       private int num, denom;


       public Rational(int num, int denom) {
           this.num = num;
           this.denom = denom;
           reduce();

        }

        public Rational add(Rational o){

            return new Rational((denom * o.num) + (o.denom * num), denom * o.denom);
        }

        public Rational sub(Rational o) {
             return new Rational((o.denom * num) - (denom * o.num), denom * o.denom);
        }

        public Rational mul(Rational o) {

            return new Rational(num * o.num, denom * o.denom);
        }

        public Rational div(Rational o) {

            return new Rational(num * o.denom, denom * o.num);
        }

        private int gcd (int num, int denom)
        {
           while (num != denom)
               if (num > denom)
                   num = num - denom;
               else
                   denom = denom - num;

               return num;
        }
        private void reduce() {
            int common = gcd(Math.abs(num), denom);
            num = num / common;
            denom = denom / common;
        }

        public String toString() {
             if (denom == 1) {
                 return(num + " ");
             }
             if (num == 0) {
                 return("0");
             } 
             else {
                 return(num + "/" + denom);
             }
        }


        public int compareTo(Rational a) {
             if ((double)(this.num)/(double)(this.denom) > (double)(a.num)/(double)(a.denom) ){
                return 1;
            }
            if ((double)(this.num)/(double)(this.denom) < (double)(a.num)/(double)(a.denom) ){
                return -1;
             }
            else {
                return 0;
                }

         }

         public double doubleValue() {
              return((double)num/denom);
         }

        public float floatValue() {
            return((float)num/denom);
        }

        public int intValue() {
            return((int)num/denom);
        }

        public long longValue() {
            return((long)num/denom);
        }
    }
```

> Update -- this code has the compareto fixed, thanks to @Izruo help

Comment: Please don't update the answers into your code. The idea of `stackoverflow` is that others might come here, searching for a problem they encounter. They will compare their code to yours and then look into the answers to see if there's something that might fix their problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when i checked my compareto method, it always returns a 0 value.

When calculating the actual value of your `Rational` you do the following:

```
double rational = (double) (this.num / this.denom);
```

This will produce `0` for any constellation where `this.num` is smaller than `this.denom`, because the calculation itself is done in `integer` arithmetic and the result is converted to a `double`.

To actually do the calculation you want to do, you have to convert each value, like this:

```
double rational = (double) this.num / (double) this.denom;
```

---

### Edit

I just tried to run your code ignoring all errors eclipse warned about. For instance, whenever I encounter compile time erros I usually don't try to execute the code, because I'm most certain something really unexpected might happen. More information below in **Note**.

> Also when I make an array of rational class elements, the program just keeps running at that point without outputting any results.

Your program runs into an infinite loop inside the `int gcd(int num, int denom)` method with the input values `num = 0` and `denom = 1`.

To solve this I recommend treating `0` values, which any value with `num = 0` certainly is (`0 / x = 0`), as a special case. In your method you should therefore add an additional check like this as the first statement:

```
if(num == 0) {
    denom = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

---

### Note

The class `Rational` misses to implement some abstract methods. I have no idea why your code is still able to run, despite having compile errors. However, I strongly recommend to fix these errors, hence implement the following methods:

- `int intValue()`
- `long longValue()`
- `float floatValue()`
- `double doubleValue()`

These are merely converting methods, so really easy to implement. In fact, the `doubleValue()` method is meant do to exactly what I explained answering the first part of your question. The other methods are just similar.

Comment: thank you for showing me the correct way of using compare to method. But regarding the rational array, is there no way, then, to create that array?

Comment: I'll be really glad if you can help me out here. And as an I did implement the above missing methods, just forgot to show them here. I will update the whole code so you can see.

Comment: @Junaid Look at the second part of my answer. It explains why your program halts.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Izruo. That made sense and worked as well